# Simplest way to disable links to external website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

First let me explain the problem:

On certain pages throughout the website im building, users can click a thumbnail of a video, and a modal (bootstrap) is displayed with that video inside, which is an embed link from various sites where the videos are hosted. The problem however, is that if the user clicks anywhere except Play/Pause, or inside the video, they are taken to the embeded videos website. 
Is there anyway i can block this?

My goal is to have the user watch the embedded video on my site and not have them leave just for clicking the video player.

Im looking for a way (possibly with jQuery), to disable any, all links while the modal is shown. Or if there is another simpler way, id love to know. Thanks!

Comment: That depends on the site you embed the video from (Something named **Copyrights**) YouTube for example has a button to watch the video on "YouTube.com", Find a player that support popular sites API (to get the video source from permalink)

Comment: Well is there any way i could Alert the user that they are going to be leaving the site? The video embed links are user submitted, i don't have much control over whether or not there is an API for the specific site the video may have come from.

Comment: You could use the ```unload``` and/or ```beforeunload``` method which vary in behavior browser to browser (version to version), but then you'd have to still distinguish what's navigation is kicked off by a click and what is through a address bar entry and/or closing of the tab/window. Keep a clicked timer perhaps along with another variable specifying the validity of the click URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't shared a snippet of your code or structure, we can only give limited suggestions. Try something like this (assuming your bootstrap modal is wrapped in a container with the id `#myModal`):

```
$('#myModal a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    /* your own logic to handle the click if you want */

    return false;
});
```

This would prevent the default action on all anchor tags (navigation in this case) and you can add your own custom handler if you want to alert the user that they are about to navigate away from the website (don't return `false` in that case).

**Update:** Since it is possible for the embedded players in your scenario to have navigation links of their own, the above snippet will not work. The best you can do is that you detect the navigation and prompt the user confirming if they really want to navigate away from your site.

First set the following event handler to detect whenever the user clicks a link in the video and is about to be navigated away from the page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (window.isPlayingVideo) {
        return "Are you sure you want to stop playing the video and leave the website?";
    }
}
```

Then, whenever the user clicks the video thumbnail to open the modal player and start playing the video, set the following flag:

```
window.isPlayingVideo = true;
```

This will prompt the user confirming if they want to leave the page (the exact UI depends on the browser). Note that you still can't disable the navigation from your code. All you can do is to give the user a choice.

Comment: The modal is wrapped in a container with the id. Ive tried this, and it works on regular text links (when placed just for testing purposes), but it doesn't stop the link from acting when clicking inside/on the video while playing or paused.

Comment: @ThatGuy343 Sorry I didn't understand the question completely before. I expanded on the answer with another possible way to handle your problem. Keep in mind that you still can't disable navigation from your code. All you can do is to prevent the navigation.

Comment: Thank you so much for elaborating on this! It works perfectly and i'm ok with giving a choice, better than just direct linking. I really appreciate the time you took to answer this :)